# How many seconds left for a sleeping process to "wake up"

Tags: linux, sleep

I would like to know if there is a way to know how many seconds are left for a sleeping process (in 'S' status) to "wake up" in LINUX.

For example, a python process I put to sleep using the sleep method.

```py
from time import sleep
sleep(60)
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want a universal answer, there probably isn't one, as it really depends on why the specific task/thread/process is sleeping, and some sleeps don't have a time bound/timeout etc.

Comment: For example, a python process I put to sleep using the sleep method. 

`from time import sleep
sleep(60)`

Answer (score 0):

A process will sleep until an interrupt is sent. This may be from a software signal or some hardware via the o/s.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, looking at this from the operating level might be an overkill. Instead consider solving it within your code, by splitting your sleep in multiple sleep statements and giving a update that way.

```py
    from time import sleep

    for i in range(0,60):
        sleep(1)
        # Give an update status via i
        print(f"I've slept {i} seconds")
```

Replace the print with something that gives an update to the OS, parses a value to a different programm etc, depending on your needs. This would be easier than trying to figure this out on an OS level.